# c# for loop in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

What is the equivalent of

```
for (int rowCounter = 0; rowCounter < rowCount; rowCounter++)
{
    for (int columnCounter = 0;columnCounter < columnCount; columnCounter++)
    {
        string strValue = GridView1.Rows[rowCounter].Cells[columnCounter].Text;
        grdTable.AddCell(strValue);
    }
}
```

in VB.net?

Comment: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/  
is great for quick translations.

Comment: Did somebody really vote this up?

Comment: @Jim thanks for wonderful link. Is really helpful for me. coz, moving to vb.net from c# .net

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
For rowCounter As Integer = 0 To rowCount - 1
    For columnCounter As Integer = 0 To columnCount - 1
        Dim strValue As String = GridView1.Rows(rowCounter).Cells(columnCounter).Text
        grdTable.AddCell(strValue)
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a very good online converter: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Converts C# to VB.NET and back.

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way to find out: compile that code, then look at it in Reflector with the language set to VB. As it is, you have information we don't have like what `grdTable` is.

Reflector doesn't *always* give valid code, but it's a very good starting point. (There are other tools available which may well do a better job of converting, but I imagine you've already got Reflector.)

For the actual code, see the other answers :)

Answer (score 1):

```
For rowCounter As Integer = 0 To rowCount-1
    'Do Stuff
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim rowCounter As Integer
For rowCounter = 0 To rowCount
    Dim columnCounter As Integer
    For columnCounter = 0 to columnCount
        Dim strValue as String
        strValue = GridView1.Rows(rowCounter).Cells(columnCounter).Text
        grdTable.AddCell(strValue)
    Next
Next
```